# Как сделать онлайн часы для другого пояса в моём случае?

Tags: javascript, timezone

Я сейчас прохожу курсы по js. И у меня было задания сделать аналоговые онлайн часы для своего региона(часового пояса). Как дополнительное задание для желающих, можно было сделать также и для других часовых поясов. Однако т.к. это доп.задание. Инфы в помощь решения не дали. Я читал статьи про timezone и ответы на похожие вопросы. Однако, как правильно это сделать для моего кода, я не понял. Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее благодарю

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;   
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background: url('forest_road.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .clock {
            width:350px;
            height: 350px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background: url(clock.png);
            background-size: cover;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0 -15px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.05),
                        inset 0 -15px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.05),
                        0 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
                        inset 0 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }

        .clock:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index: 10000;
        }

        .clock .hour, .clock .min, .clock .sec {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .clock .hour, .hr, .hr2, .hr3 {
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;
        }

        .clock .min, .mn, .mn2, .mn3 {
            width: 190px;
            height: 190px;
        }

        .clock .sec, .sc, .sc2, .sc3 {
            width: 230px;
            height: 230px;
        }

        .hr, .mn, .sc, .hr2, .hr3, .mn2, .mn3, .sc2, .sc3 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        
        .hr:before, .hr2:before, .hr3:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 8px;
            height: 80px;
            background: #ff105e;
            z-index: 10;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
        }

        .mn:before, .mn2:before, .mn3:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 4px;
            height: 90px;
            background: #fff;
            z-index: 11;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
        }

        .sc:before, .sc2:before, .sc3:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 2px;
            height: 150px;
            background: #ff105e;
            z-index: 12;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-top: 5%;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .row3, .row1 {
            padding-left: 2%;
        } 

        @keyframes animate {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);  
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Clock</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row2"> 
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="hr2" id="hr2"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="mn2" id="mn2"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="sec">
                    <div class="sc2" id="sc2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Tokio</h1>
            <h2 id="time2"></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row row1">
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="sec">
                    <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>It's my time(or your)</h1>
            <h2 id="time"></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row row3">
            <div class="clock">
                <div class="hour">
                    <div class="hr3" id="hr3"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="min">
                    <div class="mn3" id="mn3"></div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="sec">
                    <div class="sc3" id="sc3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>London</h1>
            <h2 id="time3"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> // Function of my time(your)
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
        const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
        const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

        setInterval(() => {
            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm / 12)}deg)`;
            mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">// Time recording function as a string(my or your)
        function clock(){
            var date = new Date(),
                years = (date.getFullYear()),
                weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
                week = (weekday[date.getDay()]),
                day = (date.getDate()),
                months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                month = (months[date.getMonth()]),
                hours = (date.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours(),
                minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes(),
                seconds = (date.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + " " + week + ", " + month + " " + day + ", " + years;
          }

          setInterval(clock, 1);
          clock();
    </script>   
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> // Function of my time(your)
        
        const deg2 = 6;
        const hr2 = document.querySelector('#hr2');
        const mn2 = document.querySelector('#mn2');
        const sc2 = document.querySelector('#sc2');

        setInterval(() => {
            let day2 = new Date();
            let hh = day2.getHours() * 30 ;
            let mm = day2.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day2.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr2.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm / 12)}deg)`;
            mn2.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc2.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">// Time recording function as a string(my or your)
        function clock(){
            var date = new Date(),
                years = (date.getFullYear()),
                weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
                week = (weekday[date.getDay()]),
                day = (date.getDate()),
                months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                month = (months[date.getMonth()]),
                hours = (date.getHours() < 10) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours(),
                minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes(),
                seconds = (date.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById('time2').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + " " + week + ", " + month + " " + day + ", " + years;
        }

        setInterval(clock, 1);
        clock();
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> // Function of my time(your)
        const deg3 = 6;
        const hr3 = document.querySelector('#hr3');
        const mn3 = document.querySelector('#mn3');
        const sc3 = document.querySelector('#sc3');

        setInterval(() => {
            let day3 = new Date();
            let hh = day3.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day3.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day3.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr3.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm / 12)}deg)`;
            mn3.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc3.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
        })
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">// Time recording function as a string(my or your)
        function clock(){
            var date = new Date(),
                years = (date.getFullYear()),
                weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
                week = (weekday[date.getDay()]),
                day = (date.getDate()),
                months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
                month = (months[date.getMonth()]),
                hours = (date.getHours( ) < 10) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours(),
                minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes(),
                seconds = (date.getSeconds() < 10) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById('time3').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + " " + week + ", " + month + " " + day + ", " + years;
        }

        setInterval(clock, 1);
        clock();
    </script>  
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: Какой смысл делать доп задание, если вы не понимаете, как это реализовать в ВАШЕМ коде? Посмотрите, что создает `new Date`, какие он имеет методы, а также как это можно преобразовать, чтобы получить нужный результат.

Comment: @xydore Я не прошу скидывать мне решение или тому подобное. Я немного не знал в каком ключе мне нужно искать информацию. Вы мне подсказали, спасибо) После 4-5 часов чтения различных источников я понял как это сделать. И у меня всё получилось.
На будущее, будьте более тактичными, можно было просто написать ваше второе сообщение, без первого.